# Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1 error (Already checked other questions)

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

So I've seen this question asked many times but I have not found an answer to my issue. I'm using phpmyadmin, I have 1 table with 2 columns and I have a .csv with 2 columns. My csv does not have headers and my columns are separated by ";", already changed it in phpmyadmin to "Columns separated with ;", but I still got the same error. Can anyone help?

[image: table structure]

[image: csv file]

edit: I'm using the "Import" option of phpMyAdmin to import my csv

[image: importing csv]

edit2: So I decided to export my table to see how the csv was generated. It exports like this:
"1", "1001"
"2", "1002"
Do you know why? or how can I create an csv file with the same format?
[export table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9djs.png)

Comment: please show also your code for importing the csv

Comment: oh I'm gonna edit sorry, I'm not using code I'm using "import" from phpmyadmin

Comment: Is it possible, that the first column does not count because it is an autincrement column?

Comment: yes see my answer

Comment: I also tried with just the column of my values in my csv values (in other words, just 1 cloumn) still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the manual

> When importing data into a table from a CSV file where the table has an ‘auto_increment’ field, make the ‘auto_increment’ value for each record in the CSV field to be ‘0’ (zero). This allows the ‘auto_increment’ field to populate correctly.

see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/import_export.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that does not solve it. The 0 is so that phpmyadmin generates the ID but you can write it yourself if you want (I tried with zeros and the same error :<)

Comment: use \n or \r\n for termination, look into your csv with a hex editor the probloem with not self programmed scripts is you don't know. When all fails use mysql like described in the link provided and here is more aboiut load file https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

So, what worked for me was: I exported the table as an csv and worked over that. After I was done, I imported this modified csv and it worked. It must've been what [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk) said about termination, so I guess in a way that was the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and discovered I was importing a csv table file into the wrong existing table in phpmyadmin. The number of columns was not the same, which is why I believe the error happened. Once I selected the right table, THEN clicked Import, I was able to upload successfully.